# What is the the mantra being chanted in this video?

Tags: mantras, identification-request

Could someone please tell me what mantra the person in [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-3OoPZ6Vufve_P7PCm2TIQ-1cKVCbwty/view?usp=drivesdk) is chanting?

If you do know could I have the words for this chant please.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto No It not Sri Hari Stotatram. -This is Laxami -Narasimha stotra and the meter in which it being sung  is similar  to that of Shiva Tandava  stotra.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto What SwiftPushkar wrote is not an answer. He is identifying the deity in the stotram. There are a lot of stotras dedicated to Lakshmi Narasimha. Every stotra is distinct.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I didn't say each stanza chanted in the video is distinct. There are many stotras dedicated to Lakshmi Narasimha e.g Narasimha Karavalamba stotram, Narasimha Runa vimochana stotram etc., This is also a different one. For identifying we have to listen to that stotra completely and identify where it is. Yes.This looks like a stotra (a collection) and not a mantra chanted during a homam.